# Transform and props.progess not working on react-native-web

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer, react-native-web

I have a application in React Native, and I'm applying some rotation effects to my drawer, in my application running on the phone, everything works perfectly, but when I migrate to `react-native-web` it doesn't work correctly, as you can see in the image below, the difference which stays on the screens when it runs on a cell phone and when it runs on the web.

[image]
[image]

In the web, when the drawer is closed, it still applies the rotation effect, that's doesn't could happen. I put my project into [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-dirac-5h2ji?file=/src/index.js)

To correct this problem, I tried to use `Animated.concat()`, but it still didn't work:

```js
<Animated.View
  style={[
    styles.animatedView,
    {
      borderRadius: "50px",
      transform: [
        { rotate: Animated.concat("-8deg") },
        { translateX: Animated.concat("70px") },
        { translateY: Animated.concat("20px") }
      ]
    }
  ]}
>
  <Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerTransparent: true,
      headerTitle: null,
      headerTitleAlign: "left",
      headerLeft: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
          <View style={styles.screenOptionsView}>
            <Image
              source={require("../assets/images/menu.png")}
              style={styles.screenOptionsImage}
            />
            <Text style={styles.screenOptionsText}>START</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    }}
  >
    <Stack.Screen name="Start" component={Start} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Cart" component={Cart} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Favorites" component={Favorites} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Orders" component={Orders} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</Animated.View>
```

Do you know how I can make it work on the web as well as it works on mobile?

Thank you very much in advance!!!!